# Can mystic theurge be entered early using Magical Lineage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, prestige-class, metamagic, traits

Look at the trait [Magical Lineage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/). Say at level 1 the character took a levels in *either* wizard *or* cleric. For the trait Magical Lineage, the character picks a spell that appears on *both* the cleric *and* wizard spell lists, like *[summon monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/) I.* (The trait Magical Lineage is exclusive to a single spell, not to a specific class.)

At level 1 the character also takes the feat [Heighten Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/heighten-spell-metamagic-final/). At levels 2 and 3 the character takes *either* a wizard level then a cleric level *or* vice versa. And, by level 3, the character has 3 skill ranks in both Knowledge (arcana) and Knowledge (religion).

So at level 3 by virtue of the feat Heighten Spell and trait Magical Lineage the character's able to cast a 2nd-level *summon monster I* spell as *both* an arcane spell and a divine spell. This lets the character take at character level 4 level 1 of the prestige class [mystic theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge/).

Does this work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That... doesn't really work like that.

Heighten Spell is unique in which it actually changes the effective spell level:

> Unlike other metamagic feats, Heighten Spell actually increases the
>   effective level of the spell that it modifies.

It doesn't add levels to a spell, it changes the spell level. That's subtly different.

A Silent Fireball is a 3rd level spell, even if it uses a 4th level slot. That's a +1 level increase.

A 4th Level Fireball is a 4th level spell. That's a +0 level increase.

Magical Lineage can't reduce the effective spell level, just the extra levels added by metamagic feats. Since it can't enable you to cast a 3rd level spell as a second level spell, it would make sense that heighten spell would not work with magical lineage.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding, Magical Lineage reduces the cost of metamagic feats, Heighten Spell changes the "Actual" level of the spells, when you cast a fireball heightened to 4th level it's actually a 4th level spell. The spell casting requirements for mystic theruge is the ability to cast 2nd level arcane and divine spells which you can do via heighten spell adjusting a 1st level spell to a 2nd level and it still only takes a 1st level slot because of magical lineage.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying. Because heighten spell changes a spell's actual level and magical lineage can't reduce the spell to below 2nd because its actual level IS it's actual level now.

Comment: @MrTumnus That's exactly it! You got it! :)

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote.

Comment: Seriously, not my downvote—and *awesome* for curating your nearly 3-year-old question, by the way—, and I think the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qpo) now covers this: A caster "can't apply Heighten Spell to a spell at no cost."

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thank you for pointing the FAQ, but I confess I fail to understand how that interacts with the situation at hand.  Can you help me to understand this?

Comment: If I'm reading it right (and now you've made me doubt myself!) not even the trait [Magical Lineage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/) allows a Clr2/Wiz2 to increase the effective levels of his spells using the feat Heighten Spell *for free.*

Comment: It is exactly what @HeyICanChan said, i did check the messageboards and that seems to be the interpretation of several community members. However, their interaction could get an official developer position (a FAQ), so we don't get [dozens of threads asking the same thing](http://paizo.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Store.woa/wa/search?q=magical+lineage+heighten+spell&what=messageboards).

Comment: I did not [search enough](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ohdf&page=2?Potential-Shocking-Grasp-as-a-Level-0-spell#91).

Comment: @HeyICanChan I understand, but my point on my answer is that Heighten Spell works differently than most metamagic feats in which it doesn't add a level increase (the thing that can be affected by Magical Lineage), but actually changes the _actual level_ of the spell. You can't use Magical Lineage to reduce the cost of heighten spell because Magical Lineage can't push your 4th-level fireball below 4th level.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note here:

First, **you cannot use magical lineage to bring a spell slot bellow the minimum level required to cast the spell**, as can be seen on [this FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qns). So for a 2nd level spell, that would be a 2nd level slot, for a 3rd level slot, that would be a 3rd level slot.

That said, the [FAQ clarifying Heighten Spell](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qpo) also explains that a 2nd level heightened spell is a 2nd level spell now, which means you need a minimum of 2nd level spell slot to cast the spell. Since [magical lineage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/) cannot reduce the minimum spell slot required to cast the spell, it does nothing when mixed with [Heighten Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/heighten-spell-metamagic-final/).

[Jason Buhlman](http://paizo.com/people/JasonBulmahn) (Paizo's Lead Designer) has [clarified this officially](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ohdf&page=2?Potential-Shocking-Grasp-as-a-Level-0-spell#91):

> Magical Lineage was never intended as a way for you to actually lower a spell's level. It was put in to allow you to reduce the increase from a metamagic feat. So, no unlimited magic missiles. I will see to it that the language of this ability is clarified soon and I will get this added to the FAQ.

Comment: In my reading, this makes the same point as the accepted answer.

Comment: @JaredGoguen it's the same point, using official references and developer backup.